# Get filename(s) where type is defined in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I define a class in a file

```
~/App_Code/Extensions/MyExtension/MyClass.cs
```

Is it possible to retrieve the filename by type (or 'MyExtension' part of it) without hard coding it?

```
var extTypes = getExtensions();
foreach(var extType in extTypes)
{
    // something like
    var files = extType.GetSourceFiles();

    //or maybe asp.net keeps track of types in the dynamically created assembly
    var files2 = SomeAspNetClass.WhereDidThisTypeComeFrom(extType);
}
```

Or inject it to the class in any way?

```
[ThisFile]
public class MyClass : MyBase
{
    private string _file = <thisfile>;
}
```

Comment: Like: `GetFile(typeOf(MyClass));` Will return c:\SomeApp\App_Code\Extensions\MyExtension\MyClass.cs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of information is only really available in compiled languages (like C#) when you have debugging symbols included.  So if you had a Debug build then you could get at this information by examining the current [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx).

```
var stackFrame = new StackFrame(true);
stackFrame.GetFileName()
```

Of course you probably don't want to have debug builds on your production code, so it may be worth-while looking at alternate ways to achieve whatever it is your trying to do here.

Comment: Maybe I'll just use CodeDom to compile those files at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this?

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourTypeHere)).Location
```

Comment: Will return the location of the Assembly

Comment: @magnnus ... like chramer already wrote: other information is not available without debug symbols ...